# C1 Tab Control leaving gaps if tabs are hidden

Tags: tabs, activex, componentone, farpoint

I am in the process of migrating my accounting software's usage of Farpoint's Tab Pro 2.0 to the ComponentOne Tab control.  The only problem I'm having so far is that some of my tabs will be hidden in some scenarios, like if the user has a certain combination of packages (A/R, G/L, A/P, etc.) that affect data entry.

On Tab Pro, when I made a tab not visible, it would then adjust the presentation of the tabs in a multiple-row setup such that there were no gaps, but the C1 Tab leaves the gaps, which looks bad.

Is there a way to tell the C1 Tab to not display a tab and move the subsequent tab(s) to the left to fill-in the gap(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to alter the program to work around this short-coming by arranging the tabs such that if there were only one boolean scenario, that tab or tabs would be moved to the end of the list and would then be flagged as not visible.  In cases where this was not possible or would not make sense, I had to settle for making the tabs disabled.  The reason I prefer to avoid this is because there are circumstances where there are custom variations of my software that would enable tabs, but other users might be confused with their presence.  There are also situations where the tabs could become valid/invalid based on the entry in other tabs, so they also have to be disabled.